# Kibana graphing just the difference of a metric instead of total

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I was just wondering if anybody knew of a way to be able to show a graph of the difference of metrics like system.network.in.bytes -

If you look at this graph you can just see that the value continuously gets bigger (at around the same speed) - but I just want to graph the difference between each value not the total.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4mPZ.png)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a timeseries visualization or [timelion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/timelion.html).

Assuming your field name is 'bytesIn' (for simplicity) and taking 1 minute intervals (as IMO 30s isn't possible in timelion), your timelion expression should look something like:

```
.es(*,metric='avg:bytesIn').subtract(.es(*,metric='avg:bytesIn',offset='-1m'))
```

**Explanation**

`.es(*,metric='avg:bytesIn')` gives average of `bytesIn` over a time interval (here I'm assuming `1m`)

Adding `offset='-1m'`, offsets the series retrieval by `-1m` as if they are happening now

`.subtract` just subtracts value of one series from another